# can I load a dll which is statically linked with a library

Tags: c++

I am working on a c++ project but I am getting some problem.
I have made a dll "curl_demo.dll" which is statically linked with "libcurl".Now i want to create a project "Hello1" which uses a function of "curl_demo.dll".So I want to know that can I link "curl_demo.dll" dynamically to the "Hello1" project.

Comment: Asking questions that can be simply answered yes or no is not a good idea. Describe the problem you are having. And the answer is "yes".

Comment: Don't be so afraid of trying things. You should just try it, and create a question if it doesn't work.

Comment: *I have made a dll "curl_demo.dll" which is statically linked with "libcurl"* -- That description is very confusing.  A DLL is only actually used at runtime, not when you're building the application.  So what do you mean by "which is statically linked"?  When you built the DLL, more than likely an *import library* was created, so that you can add the import library to your project.  But a DLL has absolutely nothing to do with *building* your application.  You could build an entire app successfully by using an import library, all without the DLL even being present on your system.

Comment: I don't understand, how can a *dynamically* linked library be statically linked?

Comment: @Thomas He is statically linking the DLL to another (static) library.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is certainly possible to dynamically link `curl_demo.dll` from `Hello1`.